# It appears that rospack compile is broke by tinyxml.h

Tags: ros-groovy, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rospack.cpp does not compile because the tinyxml.h file contains incorrect syntax for it to build.  Tinyxml does build itself on the machine but when the .h file is include in /usr/local/include then rospack compile fails. The tinyxml code is the latest from SourceForge sources for it.

Failure:

```
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospack'
==> make -j1 in '/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospack'
[ 16%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/src/rospack.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:0,
                 from /opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/rospack/src/rospack.cpp:59:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:1161:0: warning: "_POSIX_C_SOURCE" redefined [enabled by default]
/usr/include/features.h:163:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:1183:0: warning: "_XOPEN_SOURCE" redefined [enabled by default]
/usr/include/features.h:165:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/rospack/src/rospack.cpp: In member function ‘bool rospack::Rosstackage::exports_dry_package(rospack::Stackage*, const string&, const string&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&)’:
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/rospack/src/rospack.cpp:993:57: error: no matching function for call to ‘TiXmlElement::FirstChildElement(const string&)’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/rospack/src/rospack.cpp:993:57: note: candidates are:
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:664:22: note: const TiXmlElement* TiXmlNode::FirstChildElement() const
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:664:22: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:665:16: note: TiXmlElement* TiXmlNode::FirstChildElement()
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:665:16: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:670:22: note: const TiXmlElement* TiXmlNode::FirstChildElement(const char*) const
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:670:22: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:671:16: note: TiXmlElement* TiXmlNode::FirstChildElement(const char*)
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:671:16: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/rospack/src/rospack.cpp:995:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘TiXmlElement::NextSiblingElement(const string&)’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/rospack/src/rospack.cpp:995:45: note: candidates are:
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:644:22: note: const TiXmlElement* TiXmlNode::NextSiblingElement() const
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:644:22: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:645:16: note: TiXmlElement* TiXmlNode::NextSiblingElement()
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:645:16: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:653:22: note: const TiXmlElement* TiXmlNode::NextSiblingElement(const char*) const
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:653:22: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 

from ‘const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:654:16: note: TiXmlElement* TiXmlNode::NextSiblingElement(const char*)
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:654:16: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/rospack/src/rospack.cpp: In member function ‘bool rospack::Rosstackage::plugins(const string&, const string&, const string&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&)’:
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/rospack/src/rospack.cpp:1097:59: error: no matching function for call to ‘TiXmlElement::FirstChildElement(const string&)’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/rospack/src/rospack.cpp:1097:59: note: candidates are:
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:664:22: note: const TiXmlElement* TiXmlNode::FirstChildElement() const
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:664:22: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:665:16: note: TiXmlElement* TiXmlNode::FirstChildElement()
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:665:16: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:670:22: note: const TiXmlElement* TiXmlNode::FirstChildElement(const char*) const
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:670:22: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:671:16: note: TiXmlElement* TiXmlNode::FirstChildElement(const char*)
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:671:16: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/rospack/src/rospack.cpp:1099:47: error: no matching function for call to ‘TiXmlElement::NextSiblingElement(const string&)’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/rospack/src/rospack.cpp:1099:47: note: candidates are:
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:644:22: note: const TiXmlElement* TiXmlNode::NextSiblingElement() const
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:644:22: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:645:16: note: TiXmlElement* TiXmlNode::NextSiblingElement()
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:645:16: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:653:22: note: const TiXmlElement* TiXmlNode::NextSiblingElement(const char*) const
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:653:22: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:654:16: note: TiXmlElement* TiXmlNode::NextSiblingElement(const char*)
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:654:16: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/rospack/src/rospack.cpp: In member function ‘void rospack::Rosstackage::loadManifest(rospack::Stackage*)’:
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/rospack/src/rospack.cpp:1497:60: error: no matching function for call to ‘TiXmlDocument::LoadFile(std::string&)’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/rospack/src/rospack.cpp:1497:60: note: candidates are:

/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:1415:7: note: bool TiXmlDocument::LoadFile(TiXmlEncoding)
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:1415:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘TiXmlEncoding’
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:1419:7: note: bool TiXmlDocument::LoadFile(const char*, TiXmlEncoding)
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:1419:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:1427:7: note: bool TiXmlDocument::LoadFile(FILE*, TiXmlEncoding)
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:1427:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘FILE* {aka _IO_FILE*}’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/rospack/src/rospack.cpp: In member function ‘void rospack::Rosstackage::computeDepsInternal(rospack::Stackage*, bool, const string&)’:
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/rospack/src/rospack.cpp:1544:63: error: no matching function for call to ‘TiXmlElement::IterateChildren(const string&, TiXmlNode*&)’
/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/rospack/src/rospack.cpp:1544:63: note: candidates are:
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:562:19: note: const TiXmlNode* TiXmlNode::IterateChildren(const TiXmlNode*) const
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:562:19: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:563:13: note: TiXmlNode* TiXmlNode::IterateChildren(const TiXmlNode*)
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:563:13: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:568:19: note: const TiXmlNode* TiXmlNode::IterateChildren(const char*, const TiXmlNode*) const
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:568:19: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:569:13: note: TiXmlNode* TiXmlNode::IterateChildren(const char*, const TiXmlNode*)
/usr/local/include/tinyxml.h:569:13: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/src/rospack.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

<== Failed to process package 'rospack': 
  Command '/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env_cached.sh make -j1' returned non-zero exit status 2
Command failed, exiting.
root@raspberrypi:/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws#
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51548/it-appears-that-rospack-compile-is-broke-by-tinyxml.h/) by [bobt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3863/bobt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2013-01-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-01-06**:
Which OS, distro, architecture?

**Comment by [bobt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3863/bobt/) on 2013-01-06**:
raspbain, wheezy, armv6l This is a debian release of wheezy on the Raspberry PI with Hardware Floating Point. Using  the standard gcc complier system for armhf.  We have fuerte working on this platform.

**Comment by [bobt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3863/bobt/) on 2013-01-07**:
I  finally found from your informations the libtinyxml-dev packages that needed to be added to the machine to make it all build. Thank you for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is tinyxml with std::string and without. It has to be configured during the build procedure. In the standard tinyxml.h there is also an #ifdef for this difference. So try compiling with the define -DTIXML_USE_STL. The standard tinyxml packages for ubuntu does not have this difference it is configured for usage of std::string and has a small change in the tinyxml.h so that you do not need this flag.

cf.

http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/index.html

---

Originally posted by [2_socke](https://answers.ros.org/users/996/2_socke/) with karma: 76 on 2013-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2